# Recover $f$ if we know that $\frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let me set up the question by stating something that is well-known.  Suppose $f$ is an unknown function, but we are given $f'$ and the fact that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0. 
\end{align}
Then, by using fundamental theorem of calculus we have that
\begin{align}
f(a)-f(x)= \int_x^a  f'(t) dt
\end{align}
and by using that $f(a) \to 0$ as $a\to \infty$ we arrive at
\begin{align}
f(x)= \int_x^\infty  -f'(t) dt.
\end{align}

In other words, we can recover $f$ based on this information.

**Here is the question:** Suppose instead we know $\frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ and  $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$.  Can we still recover $f(x)$?

If we use, the previous approach we arrive at
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}= e^{-\int_x^a \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} dt}.
\end{align}
Clearly, we have a problem with this approach as we get a division by zero in the limit.

My guess is that in general, it is not possible to recover $f(x)$ based on this information. (**See one of the answers**)  However, can we do this with some extra minimal assumptions on $f$?

One trivial assumption that I would like to avoid making, is that we know $f(a)$ at some point $a$ which would make the FTC approach work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given one of your functions $f$, we can always write it as $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ where $f$ and $g$ determine each other uniquely. The condition $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ translates to $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -\infty$. Also, $\frac{d}{dx} \log(f(x)) = g'(x)$, so knowing the logarathmic derivative of $f$ equates to knowing the ordinary derivative of $g$.

Having made this translation, we see that the basic issue is that, given a function $g(x)$ with $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -\infty$, we cannot recover $g(x)$ from  $g'(x)$. For example $g(x)=-x+c$ has $g'(x) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -\infty$, regardless of the value of the constant $c$. Translating back to $f$, we can say that $f(x) = k e^{-x}$ has logarithmic derivative $-1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, regardless of the value of the constant $k$.

Comment: Good. So this gives an example that it is not possible. What about the part about imposing some constraints? If we use your example, imposing that we know $\int_0^\infty f =c$ would make it work.

Comment: Yes that would suffice. As you can see from the argument above, two (positive-valued, differentiable) functions $f_1,f_2$ have the same logarithmic derivative if and only if they differ by a positive constant, i.e. $f_1 =k f_2$. Since integration is linear, rescaling a function $f$ will change the integral $\int_0^\infty f$, assuming it is finite, so specifying that integral would indeed be enough to determine a unique function.

Comment: Ok. Quick question. if we assume that $\int_0^\infty f =c$, what would be the inverse relationship from logarithmic derivative to $f$?

Comment: You could fix some antiderivative $g_0(x)$ for $\frac{f'}{f}$, say $g_0(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \ dt$, i.e. the unique one with $g_0(0)=0$. Then you know $f(x) = k e^{g_0(x)}$ for some constant $k$. Now you can take $\int_0^\infty \cdot \ dx$ on both sides and solve in order to get a concrete expression for $k$. Substituting this expression for $k$ gives a formula for $f$ which only depends on the number $\int_0^\infty f(x) \ dx$ and the function $\frac{f'}{f}$.